# I tried this question by using pi denoting method and got a big equation what to do

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Find coefficient of $x^6$ in 
$(1+x)(1+x^2)^2.....(1+x^n)^n$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'pi denoting method'

Comment: I would assume that he is referring to how you can write summations with $\sum$ you can write products with $\prod$ and so he rewrote the above expression as $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+x^k)^k$ but couldn't continue.

Comment: Yes I did they same but no further step can be done

Comment: With the numbers as small as they are, I would probably brute force this, noting that the coefficient is the same for all $n\geq 6$ so you might as well look only at $(1+x)(1+x^2)^2\cdots (1+x^6)^6$

Comment: Yes but don't you think some coefficients would be skipped

Comment: Oops! Silly me. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A creative approach. $\prod_{k\geq 1}(1+x^k)^k$ is the exponential of
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}k \log(1+x^k) = \sum_{k\geq 1}k\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} x^{kn}=\sum_{m\geq 1}mx^m \sum_{d\mid m}\frac{(-1)^{d+1}}{d^2} $$
or
$$ x+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{10 x^3}{3}+\frac{11 x^4}{4}+\frac{26 x^5}{5}+5 x^6 + O(x^7).$$
Since $\exp(z)=1+z+o(z)$, it is enough to look for the coefficient of $x^6$ in
$$ 1+x+2 x^2+5 x^3+8 x^4+16 x^5+\color{red}{28}\, x^6 + O(x^7).$$
This coefficient can be found also through numerical integration, since it equals
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\varepsilon}\exp\left[z+\frac{3 z^2}{2}+\frac{10 z^3}{3}+\frac{11 z^4}{4}+\frac{26 z^5}{5}+5 z^6\right]\frac{dz}{z^7} $$
(any numerical approximation of this integral within an error $<\frac{1}{2}$ does the job, since we know in advance that the value of this monster is a natural number).

Answer (score 2):

Your function is effectively a generating function for the number of ways you can express a number as a sequence where the sum of the terms in the sequence is equal to our number and within the first $1$ terms all terms are either $0$ or $1$, within the next $2$ terms all terms are either $0$ or $2$, within the next $3$ terms all terms are either $0$ or $3$, etc... on up to the final $n$ terms where all terms are either $0$ or $n$.

$\underbrace{\underline{~}}_{1's}\underbrace{\underline{~}~\underline{~}}_{2's}\underbrace{\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}}_{3's}\cdots \underbrace{\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}}_{6's}$

One such sequence might be $\underbrace{\underline{0}}_{1's}\underbrace{\underline{0}~\underline{0}}_{2's}\underbrace{\underline{3}~\underline{0}~\underline{3}}_{3's}\cdots \underbrace{\underline{0}~\underline{0}~\underline{0}~\underline{0}~\underline{0}~\underline{0}}_{6's}$

I would break down into cases based on the different ways that you can reach a total of $6$ using at most one $1$'s, at most two $2$'s, at most three $3$'s, etc..., where the terms appear in (*non-strictly*) increasing order, noting that we may stop at $6$ since if we continue past $6$ the sum would be larger than $6$ if we use any of those terms anyways.

The ways you can do this are $1+2+3$, $2+4$, $3+3$, $1+5$, $6$.  You can check there are no other ways subject to our constraints.

Now, for each of these, let us figure out the number of ways to select which of the positions in our sequence receive the number in question and which receive the zeroes.  For example in the case of $1+2+3$, there is one way to choose where to place the $1$.  There are $2$ ways to choose how to place the $2$, and there are $3$ ways to choose how to place the $3$.  This gives $1\times 2\times 3$ ways to have gotten a sum of $6$ using $1$'s, $2$'s and $3$'s and enough other zeroes to fill the spaces in the sequence subject to our constraints.

Similarly there are $2\times 4, 1\times 5$ and $6$ ways in the other cases respectively.  The only one of our cases which doesn't follow this pattern is the case for $3+3$ which instead has $\binom{3}{2}=3$ options for how to distribute the $0$'s instead.

This gives a grand total of:

$$1\times 2\times 3 + 2\times 4 + 3 + 1\times 5 + 6 = 6+8+3+5+6=28$$

Comment: Actually I am 10 std student so is there a simpler method

Comment: If by "simpler" you mean "simpler" in terms of theory, yes, you can just expand your product fully...  That seems like a terrible idea and waste of time to me though.  You can save a bit more time by totally ignoring every term in the expansion and partial expansions where the exponent is larger than $6$ already.  Even with that simplification though, this seems incredibly tedious and prone to error.

Comment: In terms of simplest in terms of arithmetic, I doubt it gets any easier than what I did above.

Answer (score 1):

Notet that the coefficient of $x^6$ is
\begin{align}
\sum\prod_{k=1}^n\binom k{t_k}
\end{align}
where the sum is taken over $0\leq t_k\leq k$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^nkt_k=6$.
Note that $t_k=0$ for $k>6$.
The only possible sums $\sum_{k=1}^6kt_k=6$ are:
\begin{align}
6=1\cdot 0+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 0+5\cdot 0+6\cdot 1\\
6=1\cdot 1+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 0+5\cdot 1+6\cdot 0\\
6=1\cdot 0+2\cdot 1+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 1+5\cdot 0+6\cdot 0\\
6=1\cdot 0+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 2+4\cdot 0+5\cdot 0+6\cdot 0\\
6=1\cdot 1+2\cdot 1+3\cdot 1+4\cdot 0+5\cdot 0+6\cdot 0
\end{align}
consequently, the required coefficient is
\begin{align}
c
&=\binom 10\binom 20\binom 30\binom 40\binom 50\binom 61\\
&+\binom 11\binom 20\binom 30\binom 40\binom 51\binom 60\\
&+\binom 10\binom 21\binom 30\binom 41\binom 50\binom 60\\
&+\binom 10\binom 20\binom 32\binom 40\binom 50\binom 60\\
&+\binom 11\binom 21\binom 31\binom 40\binom 50\binom 60\\
&=6+5+8+3+6\\
&=28
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at pitching the answer as simply as possible. Hope it's easy to understand.

If you want a systematic way of multiplying those then remember that the $k^{\text{th}}$ row of Pascal's triangle gives $a_{k,r}$, the coefficients of $x^r$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^k$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
k\backslash r& x^0 & x^1 & x^2& x^3& x^4& x^5& x^6\\\hline
0 & 1 &&&&&&\\
1 & 1 & 1 &&&&&\\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 &&&&\\
3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 &&&\\
4 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 &&\\
5 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1 &\\
6 & 1 & 6 & 15 & 20 & 15 & 6 & 1\end{array}$$

Remember also that each coefficient in row $k$ column $x^r$ is found by adding the coefficients in the previous row (row $k-1$) in columns $x^r$ and $x^{r-1}$. We represent this with the recurrence

$$a_{k,r}=a_{k-1,r}+a_{k-1,r-1}$$

Each row $k$ represents the expansion of $(1+x)\times (1+x)^{k-1}$.

In a similar way we can expand your product

$$(1+x)(1+x^2)^2(1+x^3)^3\cdots (1+x^k)^k$$

by creating a table of coefficients $b_{k,r}$ in which each row $k$ represents the resulting $x^r$ coefficients $(1+x^k)^k$ multiplied by the polynomial of the previous row.

Our recurrence is now

$$b_{k,r}=a_{k,0}b_{k-1,r}+a_{k,1}b_{k-1,r-k}+a_{k,2}b_{k-1,r-2k}+a_{k,3}b_{k-1,r-3k}+\cdots$$

We can produce a table much like with Pascal's recurrence, viz:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
k\backslash r& x^0 & x^1 & x^2& x^3& x^4& x^5& x^6\\\hline
0 & 1 &&&&&&\\
1 & 1 & 1 &&&&&\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 &\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 7 & 9\\
4 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 17\\
5 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 16 & 22\\
6 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 16 & 28\end{array}$$

Here the recurrence gives each successive row by multiplying the previous row coefficients by the relevant $a_{k,r}$ values and adding the result.

Since we only want $x^6$ there is no need to expand past row $6$ column $6$. We find that calculation gets easier with each successive row due to the recurrence ignoring $b_{k-1,r-s}$ terms where $s$ is not a multiple of $k$.

So our answer is, for all $k$

\begin{array}{c|c}k & b_{k,6}\\\hline
0 & 0\\
1 &0\\
2 & 0\\
3 &9\\
4 &17\\
5 &22\\
6 &28\\
7 &28\\
\vdots &\vdots\\\end{array}

clearly the answer stays at $28$ for all $k\ge 6$.

Note: I've used $k$ instead of $n$.